# URL Rewriting or .htacess not working

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite the url like
http://test.com/1234
to
http://test.com/index.php?a=1234

and my .htaccess file

```
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule     /^[a-zA-Z0-9]/?$    index.php?key=$1    [NC,L]
```

but nothing is happening it simply shows object not found error, .htaccess file is already in the root directory so help needed
P.S. I am a beginner in rewriting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?key=$1 [NC,L]
```

- You need the brackets to group characters and re-use them as the $1 parameter.
- You don't need the `/`
- If you have a pattern like `[0-9]` you need a `*` or `+` if you want to match more than one character.

Btw, if the `key` parameter only accepts numbers, use:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?key=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$     index.php?a=$1     [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Working but giving value of a=index.php but I want it to be 1234

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`^(.*)$` results in passing down the whole request path as one parameter

`QSA` results in appending any query string to the request

`?a=$1` specify how the parameter is passed down